# Android how increase the font size of Month Selector of DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, calendarview, datepickerdialog, materialdatepicker

I would increase the size of month Selector or DatePickerdialog in my app.
DatePicker dialog stay into separate Class triggered dy OnClick
This is my relevant code portion

I create DatePickerDialog as this:

```
dpd = new DatePickerDialog(ctx, R.style.calendar_style,this,
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

[DatePickerDialof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjD1f.png)

This is th style XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style
        name="calendar_style" wparent="Theme.Itk3" zparent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen">

        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Alert.Button.Positive</item>
        <item name="android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Alert.Button.Negative</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">38sp</item>
        <item name="android:calendarViewStyle">@style/itk_calendarView</item>
        <!--item name="android:calendarViewShown">@style/itk_calendarView</item-->
        <!--item name="android:headerMonthTextAppearance">@style/dayText</item>
        <item name="android:headerYearTextAppearance">@style/dayText</item>
        <item name="android:yearListItemTextAppearance">@style/dayText</item>
        <item name="android:yearListSelectorColor">@style/dayText</item-->
        <item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/itk_calendarView</item>
    </style>
    <!-- parent="android:Widget.CalendarView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar"  -->
    <style name="itk_calendarView" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
        <item name="android:dateTextAppearance">@style/dayText</item>
        <item name="android:weekDayTextAppearance">@style/dayText</item>
        <item name="android:yearListItemTextAppearance">@style/dayText</item>
        <item name="android:yearListSelectorColor">@style/dayText</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">38sp</item>
        <!--item name="android:calendarViewShown">@style/itk_calendarView</item-->
        <!--item name="android:headerMonthTextAppearance">@style/dayText</item>
        <item name="android:headerYearTextAppearance">@style/dayText</item>
        <item name="android:yearListItemTextAppearance">@style/dayText</item>
        <item name="android:yearListSelectorColor">@style/dayText</item-->
        <!--item name="materialCalendarMonthNavigationButton">@style/navigationButtonMonthStyle</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarMonth">@style/navigationButtonMonthStyle</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarYearNavigationButton">@style/navigationButtonYearStyle</item-->
    </style>

    <style name="dayText">
        <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Alert.Button.Positive" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorDarkLmsc</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Alert.Button.Negative" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>
    <!--
    <style name="navigationButtonYearStyle" parent="Base.Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.NavigationButton">
        <item name="iconTint">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorRed</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">40sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="navigationButtonMonthStyle" parent="Base.Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.NavigationButton">
        <item name="iconTint">@color/colorRed</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorRed</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">40sp</item>
    </style>
    -->

</resources>
```

In any case the font size remain unchanged.
I guess that the Mont field  stay into a Pager, but can't modify programmatically

Also tried to use MaterialDatePicker, but with no luck